# ProcessBuilder--passing multiple parameter

Tags: java

How can i send more than two parameter here in the below program? pls advice

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", scriptPath + script, "myArg1", "myArg2");
     Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
     env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
     env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
     try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please highlight and describe the parameters

Comment: Add more parameters to the constructor call?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another value to the map:

```
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
env.put("VAR3", "one more");
```

Or you can add another argument to the constructor since it takes var args:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash",
  scriptPath + script, "myArg1", "myArg2", "myArg3");
```